# JavaScript for changing the font colour of a textarea according to the user's selection

Tags: javascript, html, colors, textarea

Ok, so I am trying to build a simple text processor that the user types some text into a textarea and then do changes to it. 
I am stuck on changing the font colour of a textarea according to the user's selection. Do you have any ideas how to do that? Either with a colour picker or a drop-down list.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/2x12nzjt/)

```
<textarea>Some text</textarea>
<select>
    <option value="#000000">black</option>
    <option value="#FF0000">red</option>
    <option value="#0000FF">blue</option>
    <option value="#00FF00">green</option>
</select>

<script> //jQuery, but you can do the same with vanila JS
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $('textarea').css('color', $(this).find(':selected').val());
});
</script>
```

Unless you need something else.